# way to compile assembler code

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, 16-bit, windows64

just started learning Assembler in school, and want to ask
how to compile this code:

```
stek Segment Stack
DB 256 DUP(?)
stek ENDS

CR EQU 13
EF EQU 10

Duom SEGMENT
pranesimas DB 'Hello Word', CR,EF
           DB 'Made By Edgar' $
Duom ENDS


prog SEGMENT

ASSUME CS:programa,ds:Duomenis,ss:stekas

START:
        MOV ax,duomenis
        MOV ds,ax

        MOV ah,09
        LEA dx,Pranesimas
        INT 21h


        MOV ah,4ch
Prog ENDS

END START
```

on windows 7 x64

because in school we have Xp x32, the way we compile in school does not work on x64 windows.

Comment: `the way we compile in school does not work on x64 windows` Clarify.

Comment: just it writes "... is not compatible with this version of windows..."

Comment: @JensBjörnhager The program he is trying to assemble is a 16 bit DOS program that afaik won't run on anything newer than XP without something like [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/information.php?page=0)

Comment: Please, we do not compile Assembly code, we Assemble and optionally link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer versions of Windows have dropped the 16-bit support that used to be there in XP, so to compile the program (a 16 bit DOS program), you'll need to install [DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/information.php?page=0), [Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) or similar emulator.

They will emulate the 16-bit environment so you should be able to run DOS with both the assembler and resulting code on your 64-bit Windows (or Mac/Linux machine for that matter)